# Tidyverse Solution for Using Tibble Columns as Input to a Function

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I am trying to run a function on all on combinations of two column vectors in a tibble.

```
library(tidyverse)
combination <- tibble(x = c(1, 2), y = c(3, 4))

sum_square <- function(x, y) {
  x^2+y^2
}
```

I would like to run this function all combinations of column x and column y:

```
sum_square(1, 3)
sum_square(1, 4)
sum_square(2, 3)
sum_square(2, 4)
```

Ideally I would like a tidyverse solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can first `expand` and then apply `sum_square` on the expanded dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
expand(combination, x, y) %>% 
      mutate(new = sum_square(x, y))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#      x     y   new
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     3    10
#2     1     4    17
#3     2     3    13
#4     2     4    20
```

---

Another option is `outer`

```
combination %>%
       reduce(outer, FUN = sum_square) %>% 
       c  %>%
       tibble(new = .)
```

Comment: Thanks! Expand is very useful. What if I wanted to run these set of functions outside of a mutate command? The example was just a reprex.

Comment: @CaseyBreen  Which all functions are admissible?

Comment: Most I believe... for example, imagine the function sum_square returned a tibble. thanks!